# EventHandler not working?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have this method for buttons

```
private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < buttons.Length; c++)
            {
                if (buttons[c] == sender)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < ci.Length; d++)
                    {
                        if (buttons[c].Text == ci[d].getName().Substring(0, 1))
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Clear();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(ci[d].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code should display the names that matches the first letter of each names for every button.
I have already define the method as new event for every buttons.
ci is constructor with 31 objects
the buttons is an array of 26 buttons and all have properties defined

Comment: Are you sure you've actually bound the event to the buttons?

Comment: yes coz' I tried displaying a messagebox containing the button clicked

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing `listBox1` every time you go to add a new item into it c.O Idk if you're meaning to do that or not.

Also, get the *ID* of the sending button like

```
Button myBtn = sender as Button;
string myID = myBtn.ID;
```

And then try changing this if statement `if (buttons[c] == sender)` to something like this:

```
if(buttons[c].ID == myID)
{...}
```

Comment: oh thanks for your reply

yes I clear the listBox1 coz there is already an initial text in inside the listBox

why will I change the if statement btw? :D

Comment: Yeah, but don't you mean to only clear it once per button click? If so, you should clear() it at the start of the eventhandler function, or else you'll always end up with one item, the last item you entered. You should change your if statement because you're comparing whole button objects to the generic object type, which I don't know how stable that will be.. If anything, at least change it to `if (buttons[c] == sender as Button)`

Comment: yeah, youre right at the clear() thing. thanks
i tried changing the if statement but nothing happens :|

Comment: Well then your problem probably lies within the `buttons` array or `ci` array. Run your debugger and step through the code to see what's going on. good luck! remember to "mark as answer" if my answer helped you^^